# Is pseudo code needed in today's programming?

Tags: pseudocode

Should I learn pseudo code to learn Data-structures and Algorithms? Or is it actually needed?

Is pseudo code used any more in modern day software development?

Is pseudo code taught in colleges any more?

Comment: Pseudo code is simply "stuff that looks like code but isn't". Programmers tend to use it to explain simple concepts and ideas to each other, usually based on a real programming language. Lean a few of those and 'getting' pseudo code will come naturally.

Comment: Do you have any concrete examples in mind?

Comment: While searching for some college lecture-notes about Algorithms in the Internet, I found that, algorithms are mostly described in pseudo codes. So the question came in my mind whether the teachers are insisting to write Algorithms in the form of pseudo codes in the exams. If so, what benefits are they expecting from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data structures and algorithms are usually taught in some existing languages. Pseudo code is still being used nowadays, but because it’s usually very close to some widely known language, there’s not much to learn and I don’t think they teach that in colleges. At least I hope not :)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code is informal; it's one way to communicate your ideas and algorithms to others. There's not much to learn. If you understand data structures and algorithms and can explain them in english, then you already do know pseudo code.

If you want real, usable pseudo code, [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) is the closest thing I've seen that resembles readable pseudo code if elegance and readibility are important considerations.